# Problems with installing Lubuntu on a Fedora laptop

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, fedora

I have Fedora installed on my laptop but want to switch to Lubuntu.

My first problem is with deleting Fedora because I get an error if I try to wipe the disk during the installation of Lubuntu.

I chose manual partitioning and deleted the Fedora partitions (at least I tried deleting them) and the installation started, but it crashed when it reached around 95%. I started the setup again but got another error.

How do I fix that?

Here is what I did:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Try starting in live. And do it from there. Otherwise use fdisk.

Comment: @An0n This was done from a live version

Comment: I mean did you choose test lubuntu?

Comment: @An0n  I chose the first option during boot-up. I managed to installed and got the message that it is successfully installed and that I have to restart my PC. When I restarted, it couldn't boot and I got a message that said that there are no bootable devices. Even when I went to the bios settings, the boot option were empty. I booted from the usb again and found out that the partitions are there and it even says Lubuntu on one of them.

Comment: Did the installation finish?

Comment: Yes, adn it said I have to reboot the pc or I can continue using the live image, but when I turned it back on, it said that there aren't any bootable devices, so I had to plug in the usb again. Then I saw that all the partitions are still there, but i can't access them.

Comment: Use boot-repair

Comment: @An0n is it possible to use boot repair from a live image since I can't access the OS?

Comment: Offcourse.. Did You try?

Comment: @An0n  yes, managed to do it. Works great now. Thanks